# gcloud nodejs datastore: how to create an entity with a parent?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-node

How to create an entity with a parent using `gcloud`, `datastore` and `nodejs`?

How to search for all the entities with a given parent?

Something like (this does not work):

```
var path = [{kind: 'Parent', id: parentId}, {kind: 'Me'}];
var key = ds.key(path);
var entity = {
  key: key,
  data: toDatastore(data, ['description'])
};
ds.save(entity)
```

Reading the docs I did not find any example of creating an entity with a given parent. I searched (without success) here:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.19.1

while on the counterpart in python there are some specific proprieties to specify the parent entity:
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/latest/datastore-keys.html

Please provide an example of code of how create and search for an entity with a parent

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want something like:

```
var key = ds.key(['Parent', parentId, 'Me']);
```

- [Key docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.19.1/datastore/dataset?method=key)

Comment: The link returns 404 now. Working: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities